# SVG animation on hover starts from wrong position in firefox

Tags: animation, firefox, svg, transform, transition

When you hover on element in Chrome, the bottom part of the clock starts moving down. If you try to do this in firefox, it starts from wrong position.

HTML

```
<g id="clock_bottom_3" opacity="0.316786674" transform="translate(72.000000, 306.000000)">
                    <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-1)" opacity="0.24" transform="translate(87.000000, 52.000000) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-87.000000, -52.000000) " cx="87" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                    <ellipse id="Oval" fill="url(#radialGradient-2)" opacity="0.24" transform="translate(117.000000, 52.000000) scale(-1, 1) rotate(-180.000000) translate(-117.000000, -52.000000) " cx="117" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
                </g>
```

CSS:

```
#clock_bottom_3 {transition: transform 0.3s;}
svg:hover #clock_bottom_3 {transform: translate(72px, 320px);}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kd7x068g/

Comment: Not sure how much FF is right here, nor how things will change with the upcoming svg2 standards, but indeed, it seems FF doesn't allow CSS transitioning from `transform` attribute to its CSS equivalent. An easy workaround is to use css everywhere : https://jsfiddle.net/kd7x068g/1/

Comment: no but it should still apply the non-CSS transform.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you might have struck a bug in Firefox.

Here's a simplified version of your SVG:

```css
#clock_bottom_3 {transition: transform 0.3s;}

svg:hover #clock_bottom_3 {transform: translate(72px, 320px);}
```

```html
<svg width="588px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 588 512">
    <g id="clock_bottom_3" transform="translate(72 306)">
        <ellipse fill="blue" cx="87" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
    </g>
</svg>
```

You are transitioning between two `translate()` transforms on hover.  This works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox.  It appears as if Firefox is ignoring the initial transform on the object and transitioning from (0,0) instead.

The fix for now is to wrap "clock_bottom_3" in another group and apply the transition to that instead.

```css
#clock_bottom_3_wrap {transition: transform 0.3s;}

svg:hover #clock_bottom_3_wrap {transform: translate(0px, 14px);}
```

```html
<svg width="588px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 588 512">
    <g id="clock_bottom_3_wrap">
        <g id="clock_bottom_3" transform="translate(72 306)">
            <ellipse fill="blue" cx="87" cy="52" rx="87" ry="52"></ellipse>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[If we make that modification to your original fiddle, it works.](https://jsfiddle.net/kd7x068g/2/)